# Firebase crash SecurityException DynamiteModulesC

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, firebase-crash-reporting

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to start service Intent { act=com.google.firebase.crash.internal.service.FirebaseCrashReceiverService.SAVE cmp=com.sample.android/com.google.firebase.crash.internal.service.FirebaseCrashReceiverService (has extras) }: Unable to launch app com.sample.android/10124 for service Intent { act=com.google.firebase.crash.internal.service.FirebaseCrashReceiverService.SAVE cmp=com.sample.android/com.google.firebase.crash.internal.service.FirebaseCrashReceiverService }: process is bad
   at android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1720)
   at android.app.ContextImpl.startService(ContextImpl.java:1693)
   at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService(ContextWrapper.java:516)
   at aii.run(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC:181)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Firebase crash is set up perfectly as we are getting reports of the crashes BUT i'm seeing this on Crashlytics and this ultimately leads to crashing the app.

Does anyone know what this problem is?

Comment: Firebase Crash sends crash reports to a background thread via an Intent. This stack trace is indicating that background process is in a bad state, but - this will only happen if there is a crash happening already. How commonly are you seeing this crash? There are definitely odd things that can occur to the process, but they should be rare.

Comment: It definitely is not a rare event. In one day with almost 500 users I can easily trace up to 20 events atleast

Comment: If you search Stack Overflow for "process is bad" you'll see a bunch of unresolved or weakly-resolved issues that could only be addressed by rebooting.  My guess is that this is an Android platform issue and not something that can be addressed by the app itself.  My guess is that most of your crashes are being triggered by a single active user who has yet to reboot their device.  Are you able to tell in Crashlytics if this might be the case?

Comment: I had given the weekend to see whether this is turning around to be a pressing issue. Fortunately it is not. As much as this doesn't seem to be a reboot related issue, crashlytics and fabric haven't been increasing in an alarming rate. But it still is present.

Comment: I'm seeing the same error for a Samsung GT-I9060I with Android 4.4.4

Comment: I've yesterday published an app with FirebaseCrash and i see this issue, have done something on the client side to fix this or its a FirebaseCrash known issue?